# try to save and return sub doc inside mongoose promise but it not save and make some error how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, database, mongoose

const assert = require("assert");
const User = require("../src/user");

describe("sub document ",()=>{

```
it("can push the title",(done)=>{

        var joe = new User({
            name : "joe",
            pp : []
        })
        joe.save()
            .then(()=>{
                return User.findOne({name : "joe"});
            }).then((name)=>{
                console.log(name);
                 name.pp.push({title : "hi"});

                return name.save(); 

                 }).then(()=>{
                    return user.findOut({name:"joe"});
                 }).then((user)=>{
                     assert(user.pp[0].title === "hi");
                     done();
                 })

            })
        })
```

enter image description here[error message showing on the cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz4mW.png)

**return name.save()** is the problem maker i try without return and after saving then return the user it's not work to .checked  promises and it's work
please tell me how to fix this using only promises

Comment: user.findOut({name:"joe"}); --- try using 'User' object instead of 'user' . Try with User.findOut({name:"joe"})

Comment: also, i don't know what is findOut in User.findOut. may be you wanted User.findOne there.